# React radio buttons not displaying in browser

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am new to React and formik and struggling to get my radio buttons to display in the browser. I think it is because the radio buttons are not defined as props in my formikcontrol function. How do I add it to the other props in my formikcontrol function? Please advise how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import FormikContainer from './components/FormikContainer';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import Registrationform from './components/RegistrationForm';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <LoginForm />
      <Registrationform />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

RegistrationForm:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import FormikControl from './FormikControl';

function Registrationform() {
  const options = [
    { key: 'Email', value: 'emailmoc' },
    { key: 'Telephone', vlaue: 'telephonemoc' }
  ];

  const initialValues = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
    modeOfContact: '',
    phone: ''
  };

  const validationSchema = yup.object({
    email: yup.string().email('Invalid email format').required('Required'),
    password: yup.string().required('Required'),
    confirmPassword: yup
      .string()
      .oneOf([yup.ref('password'), ''], 'Passwords must match')
      .required('required'),
    modeOfContact: yup.string().required('Required'),
    phone: yup.string().when('modeOfContact', {
      is: 'telephonemoc',
      then: yup.string().required('Required')
    })
  });

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log('Form data', values);
  };
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
    >
      {(formik) => {
        return (
          <Form>
            <FormikControl
              control="input"
              type="email"
              label="Email"
              name="email"
            />

            <FormikControl
              control="input"
              type="password"
              label="Password"
              name="password"
            />

            <FormikControl
              control="input"
              type="password"
              label="Confirm Password"
              name="confirmPassword"
            />

            <FormikControl
              control="radio"
              type="Mode of contact"
              label="modeOfContact"
              options={options}
            />
            <FormikControl
              control="input"
              type="text"
              label="Phone number"
              name="phone"
            />

            <button type="submit" disabled={!formik.isValid}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
}

export default Registrationform;
```

FormikControl:

```
import React from 'react';

function FormikControl({ control, id, label, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <>
      {control === 'input' && <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>}
      <input id={id} {...rest} />
    </>
  );
}

export default FormikControl;
```

FormikContainer:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import FormikControl from './FormikControl';

function FormikContainer() {
  const initialValues = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  };
  const validationschema = Yup.object({
    email: Yup.string().required('Required')
  });
  const onSubmit = (values) => console.log('Form data', values);

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationschema={validationschema}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      >
        {(formik) => (
          <Form>
            <FormikControl
              control="input"
              type="email"
              label="Email"
              name="email"
            />

            <FormikControl
              control="input"
              type="password"
              label="Password"
              name="password"
            />

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FormikContainer;
```

Comment: Hi Lizzy :)
Let me copy your code and try to test it on sandbox, i'll come later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get radio button rendered using Formik, you have to import Field component and use it by sending type="radio", here is how it should look like:
[enter link description here](https://formik.org/docs/examples/radio-group)

Or by using the same component you created but with type="radio" :

```
<FormikControl
 control="input"
 type="radio"
 .....
/>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help...the label modeOfContact displays now but with only 1 radio button. How do I get the second radio button to display? I'm trying to get my form to look like the one in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTQcsmagl1I&t=34s

Comment: I used the <FormikControl
 control="input"
 type="radio"
 .....
/> code you suggested

Comment: Hi Lizzy, just visit the link i sent in my answer to see the documentation of Formik, but in general you have to have like a group of radio buttons , we can do some pair code if you prefer

Comment: Thank you it works. I made the following group of buttons: <div className="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" value="Phone" options={options} />
                  Phone
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" value="Email" options={options} />
                  Email
                </label>
              </div>

Comment: I am just having problems aligning the radio button horizontally. I used a className radio but when I use .radio{} in the css file - it does not make any changes. Can you please advise